# Find markers shown in mapView

Tags: swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to determine the marker/s currently shown in a mapview. I have researched the following the method:

`self.mapView.bounds.contains(markers[0].position)`

But the `contains` command accepts CGPoint or CGRect. In other platforms except Swift, `contains` can accept the marker's position.

How do I convert the marker's position to be accepted by `contains`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the mapview's current `projection`. Use the projection's method called `containsCoordinate` to check if you marker's position is inside the projection, i.e. currently visible.

So something like:

```
let coord = marker.position
let isVisible = self.mapview.projection.containsCoordinate(coord)
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_projection.html#aa6ad29e6831e40f00435c3aaeda8e08a

Comment: Alternatively, you can try to convert the marker's positions to screen points using the projection too.

Comment: My marker is inside the map but few portion of marker is outside the map. How could I know that? I have tried using projection to convert the lat long to screen point but sometimes it gives me negative value. Can you have a working sample code of projection?

Answer (score 3):

**In MapKit**:

I assume with Marker you mean an `MKAnnotation`. Instead of using the bounds of the `mapView` you should use the `visibleMapRect` and see if it contains the coordinates of the Marker in `MKMapPoints`. This is the code I used:

```
let markerPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(markers[0].coordinate)
if MKMapRectContainsPoint(mapView.visibleMapRect, markerPoint) {
    print("Found")
} else {
    print("Not found")
}
```

Only when the coordinates of the markers are visible (in other words, the marker is being displayed), this will print "Found". If off-screen, it will print "Not found".

Comment: I just realised that you tagged "google-maps-sdk-ios", I was referring to `MapKit`. Sorry about that. Please make it clear in your question since both APIs are very similar.